# web audio API crashing chrome

Tags: google-chrome, web-audio-api

I'm trying to build something using the processor node [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScriptProcessorNode).  Almost anything I do in terms of debugging it crashes chrome.  Specifically the tab.  Whenever I bring up dev tools, and 100% of the time i put a breakpoint in the `onaudioprocess` node, the tab dies and I have to either find the chrome helper process for that tab or force quit chrome altogether to get started agin.  Its basically crippled my development for the time being.  Is this a known issue?  Do I need to take certain precautions to prevent chrome from crashing?  Are the real time aspects are the web audio api simply not debuggable?

Comment: I have used the (now deprecated) ScriptProcessorNode, and I feel that it actually tries to process every sample there is, not skipping over parts, like the newer analyser node for example. Thus I experienced complete stalls (not immediate crashes though) on computation heavy processing. If your processing does not need to process all samples, maybe you can give the analyser node a try?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, it's a bit hard to diagnose the problem.

Does running this code snippet crash your browser tab?

```js
let audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

function onPlay() {
  let scriptProcessor = audioCtx.createScriptProcessor(4096, 2, 2);
  scriptProcessor.onaudioprocess = onAudioProcess;
  scriptProcessor.connect(audioCtx.destination);

  let oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator();
  oscillator.type = "sawtooth";
  oscillator.frequency.value = 220;
  oscillator.connect(scriptProcessor);
  oscillator.start();
}

function onAudioProcess(event) {
  let { inputBuffer, outputBuffer } = event;

  for (let channel = 0; channel < outputBuffer.numberOfChannels; channel++) {
    let inputData = inputBuffer.getChannelData(channel);
    let outputData = outputBuffer.getChannelData(channel);

    for (let sample = 0; sample < inputBuffer.length; sample++) {
      outputData[sample] = inputData[sample];
      
      // Add white noise to oscillator.
      outputData[sample] += ((Math.random() * 2) - 1) * 0.2;

      // Un-comment the following line to crash the browser tab.
      // console.log(sample);      
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="onPlay()">Play</button>
```

If it crashes, there's something else in your local dev environment causing you problems, because it runs perfectly for me.

If not, then maybe you are doing a `console.log()` (or some other heavy operation) in your `onaudioprocess` event handler? Remember, this event handler processes *thousands* of audio samples every time it is called, so you need to be careful what you do with it. For example, try un-commenting the `console.log()` line in the code snippet above – your browser tab will crash.

Comment: i've been aware of console.logs slowing down the onaudioprocess rendering.  it isn't slowing down thats the problem, its complete stalling, similar to experiencing infinite recursion.  the tab becomes 100% unresponsive.  still, this always happens to me when i put a breakpoint in onaudioprocess.  major pain because i cannot easily debug my processing logic.